# C++で2進数文字列を10進数文字列に直接変換したい

Tags: c++, アルゴリズム

現在、c++で多倍長整数クラスBigIntを作成しているのですが、toString()の実装に行き詰まっています。数値を2進数文字列に変換するのはできましたが、それを更に10進数文字列に変換する方法がわかりません。
2進数文字列を10進数文字列に直接変換する方法がありましたらご教授ください。

Comment: BigIntの四則演算がすでに完成しているのであれば、BigIntを直接10進数文字列にする方がはるかに簡単だと思います。どうしても「2進数文字列を10進数文字列に直接変換する」必要があるのでしょうか?2進数を10進表現に変換するにはそれなりの演算が必要ですから、どうしても「2進数文字列を10進数文字列に直接変換」しようと思うと、「文字列に対する数値演算を定義する」と言う、BigIntと同等かそれ以上に困難な作業が必要となるでしょう。

Comment: いいえ、2進数文字列から10進数文字列に変換しなければいけないわけではなく、2進数の値よりも文字列のほうが10進数文字列に近い(?)、変換しやすいと思ったためこのように質問した次第です。

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。これからご質問を書かれる際は、「本当にやりたいこと」と「自分で考えてこんな方法を思いついた」と言う事柄をうまく分離して書かれると、多くの方が回答を書きやすくなるかと思います。またご質問を書かれる際には参考にしていただければ幸いです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。次回以降改善できるように努めます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

わざわざ２進数文字列を経由しなくても値から直接１０進数文字列にするほうが手っ取り早いです。っていうか `BigInt` 値を２進数文字列に変換できたのなら同様の手続きでｎ進数文字列に変換できるはず。

というわけで質問に対する直接的な答えではなく値の文字列化を行う方法ならば `printf()` や `<iomanip>` で可能な修飾を考えないとき

- 元の数をｎで割った剰余が１の桁の値なので文字化
- 元の数をｎで割った商が０になったら終了、０でないとき商を使って繰り返し文字化
- 下の桁から文字が得られるので逆順に蓄積して出力
- ｎを１０とすれば１０進数文字列への変換、２なら２進数、１６なら１６進数
- 前後にちょっと処理が必要だけどｎ＝６４とすれば `base64`

っすよね。実用上は必ず修飾が欲しくなると思います。計算しながら修飾するもよし、シンプル文字列が得られてから加工するもよし。